# Delete a Facebook posted messages by using the Facebook GRAPH API? (For Android)

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-ndk

I'm stuck on delete a Facebook wall posts by using Facebook GRAPH API, which is for android.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

The above site is which i use for the delete part.

and I put method into param and override delete through http method.

I request the publish_stream, read_stream, user_photos, email during Facebook login to get a permission.

```
private void deleteStatus() {
    try {
        String id = "100003613093757_108952429235193"; // I put another ID               //for test. 
        Bundle param = new Bundle();
        param.putString("method", "delete");
        BasicInfo.FacebookInstance.request(id, param, "POST");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is, this only comes out with false. This is when I implement the method, which is requested address in chrome, through the Logcat.

Answer (score 2):

You can only delete Facebook statuses that your app created.  If the user made the post with a different app or on Facebook's website, you can not delete it with your app via the Facebook API.