# Delete Facebook posted message

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete a Facebook posted messages by using the Facebook GRAPH API? (For Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700837/delete-a-facebook-posted-messages-by-using-the-facebook-graph-api-for-android)

I would like to delete Facebook post messages.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/  -----> delete part.

```
  private void deleteStatus() {      
                try {         
       String id = "100003613093757_108952429235193"; // I put another ID  
       Bundle param = new Bundle();         
       param.putString("method", "delete");         
       BasicInfo.FacebookInstance.request(id, param, "POST");     
       } catch (Exception ex) {        
          ex.printStackTrace();    
      } 
    }
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Well, what *is* wrong with it? (That is, what is expected, and what "doesn't work" and what the results of debugging/testing have shown...)

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP method is the third parameter to request (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/request/).  So you want DELETE where you have written POST, and you can remove the the method from the bundle.  This should work:

```
private void deleteStatus() {      
                try {         
       String id = "100003613093757_108952429235193"; // I put another ID  
       Bundle param = new Bundle();         
       BasicInfo.FacebookInstance.request(id, param, "DELETE");     
       } catch (Exception ex) {        
          ex.printStackTrace();    
      } 
    }
```

If that doesn't do it for you, could you share the error you're getting?

Comment: thanks sean but doesn't work. i would like to show my error and  how can i share my error with you?? if you give me your email, i'll send it to you. thanks for help